# Player was not declared in this scope(QmediaPlayer)

Tags: c++, qt, qmediaplayer

Hello I am trying to get to run the example from this site:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/videooverview.html
My code is the following:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QVideoWidget>
#include <QMediaPlayer>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    player = new QMediaPlayer;

    playlist = new QMediaPlaylist(player);
    playlist->addMedia(QUrl("http://example.com/myclip1.mp4"));
    playlist->addMedia(QUrl("http://example.com/myclip2.mp4"));

    videoWidget = new QVideoWidget;
    player->setVideoOutput(videoWidget);

    videoWidget->show();
    playlist->setCurrentIndex(1);
    player->play();

    return a.exec();



}
```

When I try to execute it I get the errors:

error: 'player' was not declared in this scope
     player = new QMediaPlayer;
     ^
/home/roman/Downloads/Dropbox/PAdI/GuiAppTest/untitled/main.cpp:15: error: 'playlist' was not declared in this scope
     playlist = new QMediaPlaylist(player);
     ^
/home/roman/Downloads/Dropbox/PAdI/GuiAppTest/untitled/main.cpp:15: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class QMediaPlaylist'
     playlist = new QMediaPlaylist(player);
                                         ^
I use Qt 5 and QT widget template. What is wrong?

Comment: do you have `QT += multimedia` in your qmake project file?

Answer (score 2):

The error os correct, you need to declare player and playlist (probably at the begin of main):

```
QMediaPlayer* player;
QMediaPlaylist* playlist;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I just learned that these examples are probably not c++ based, therefore they dont work... It works if one adjusts the commands

Comment: Yes, it is C++. The example is not a complete program, just an example of how to use the class.